# JCR new Nodetype with custom Properties

Tags: java, jcr, repository

I am using this code to write files in my Modeshape JCR repository.

```
Session session = //some session
Node folderNode = session.getRootNode();

//init some calendar and a file from fileSystem
Calendar lastModified = Calendar.getInstance();
File myFile = new File("c://temp//pic.jpg");    

//create nt:file node
Node fileNode = folderNode.addNode(myFile.getName(), "nt:file");

// create the mandatory child node - jcr:content
Node resNode = fileNode.addNode("jcr:content", "nt:resource");
resNode.setProperty("jcr:mimeType", "");
resNode.setProperty("jcr:encoding", "");
resNode.setProperty("jcr:lastModified", lastModified);

// add some binary data                    
InputStream stream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(myFile));
Binary binary = session.getValueFactory().createBinary(stream);
lastModified.setTimeInMillis(myFile.lastModified());
resNode.setProperty("jcr:data", binary);
```

I want to add some custom Property like this

```
resNode.setProperty("myCustomProperty", "some value", PropertyType.STRING)
```

But as described in all documentation, i get an `ConstraintViolationException` because of trying to add a custom property to native JCR nodeType.

I have tried to generate a new NodeType which heritates from Native `nt:resource`, and then extending it with my custom property:

```
Session session = //some session
Workspace workspace = session.getWorkspace();
NodeTypeManager nodeTypeManager = workspace.getNodeTypeManager();
NodeTypeTemplate ndt = nodeTypeManager.createNodeTypeTemplate();

//i define my new custom propertie under the new nodeType
PropertyDefinitionTemplate createPropertyDefinitionTemplate = nodeTypeManager.createPropertyDefinitionTemplate();
createPropertyDefinitionTemplate.setName("myCustomProperty");
createPropertyDefinitionTemplate.setRequiredType(PropertyType.STRING);
ndt.getPropertyDefinitionTemplates().add(createPropertyDefinitionTemplate);

String myNodeTypeName = "newCustimNodeType";
ndt.setName(myNodeTypeName);
//heritates from nt:resource
String[] str = {"nt:resource"};
ndt.setDeclaredSuperTypeNames(str);
nodeTypeManager.registerNodeType(ndt, true);
session.save();
```

Doing this we avoid `ConstraintViolationException` but now we get an `RepositoryException` because JCR is not able to save in fileSystem my new type of node with message:

"Valid primary types are nt:file, nt:folder, nt:resource, and dna:resouce"

So I guess I am not succesfully heritating new newNode from superClass `nt:resource`.

Is this the proper approach to add custom properties to a node?
Is this the proper way of defining a new nodeType heritating from a jcr native one?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to create custom node types. Rather, you can use JCR mixins to add more properties to the built-in "nt:file" and "nt:folder" node types. See this [blog post](http://modeshape.wordpress.com/2010/09/01/custom-properties-on-ntfile-and-ntfolder-nodes/) that explains how to do that.

As for the problem of defining your own custom "nt:file" and "nt:folder" subtypes, it sounds like you're using an older version of ModeShape (2.x rather than 3.x), and that you're using the file system connector. The latter was designed to expose existing files on the filesystem through ModeShape and the JCR API, and as such it is limited in the kinds of primary types for nodes it works with. Using mixins as noted in the blog post will work around this limitation. Or, consider other connectors that don't have this limitation.

Comment: Since We are not using CND Files, there is a way of creating and registering these new mixin programatically?

Comment: Yes. The JCR API's NodeTypeManager provides a way of creating node type definitions via mutable "templates". Those templates are definitions, and can be registered using the manager.